# Django URLs file error

Tags: python, django, url, web

I have the following urls.py file in a Django project, and I am getting an error which I assume is relating to the latest syntax relating to urls and paths.

The **code** I have in the urls file which is url.py in the mysite (outermost directory) is:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include 


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', include('aboutme.urls')),

]
```

The **error** message is:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

In the actual app (website folder) which is called 'aboutme', the urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include 
from .import views #this is the main thing we are going to be doing ....returning views!

urlpatterns = [

        path(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),

]
```

Can anyone shed any light on the correct syntax or what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I also went back and tried to update the main mysite's url.py file to include the admin commands (which were in the previously working version). The code and resultant error are also shown below:

**Tried this code:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include 


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r' ', include('aboutme.urls')),

]
```

**Error**

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Your updated code `r' '` has a space in it. You should use the empty string `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` in the `urls.py` files.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include 

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('aboutme.urls')),
]
```

And in your app `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include 
from .import views #this is the main thing we are going to be doing 

app_name="myappname"
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

In django 2.0 they are not needed anymore if you are using `path()`.

Related link: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28691

Comment: I tried that but it comes up with : Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
The empty path didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: It's not that they are not needed any more, but that they are not used with `path()`. `url()` still exists, and you *would* use them with that.

Comment: Just tried it - but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Do I need to specify the name of the app? (directory I am trying to connect to)

Comment: Where? Can you put that in your code (answer) please?

Comment: Done. I also added a link that might help

Comment: So, just to clarify, your suggestion is to add the app_name (in this case "aboutme" directory) in the aboutme urls.py file, not the outer most directory? Will try it now.

Comment: Okay, tried it. Your first suggestion to remove the ^ and $ was perfect, along with the space I had. As it happens, I didn't need the app_name to be declared, it worked without. Thank you!